# Why is dcast populating my (melted) dataframe with NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, melt

I began with this innocuous dataframe:

```
Date          Company     Jobs   
1/1/2012      Company 1    12 
1/1/2012      Company 2    84
1/1/2012      Company 3    239
1/1/2012      Company 4    22
```

I am dreaming, begging, and fantasizing about this dataframe looking like this:

```
Date          Company 1   Company 2 Company 3 Company 4
1/1/2012         12          84       239        22
1/2/2012                
1/3/2012                     <other numbers here> 
1/4/2012
```

Looking around and thinking about which tools to use, I figured I'd use the reshape2 package.
I started with  `myDF <- melt(myDF)`
so I could melt my dataframe.  The strategy is to use
`dcast` to reformat it as a long dataframe.

So here's my melted dataframe:

```
Date          Company     variable   value
1/1/2012      Company 1    Jobs       12 
1/1/2012      Company 2    Jobs       84
1/1/2012      Company 3    Jobs       239
1/1/2012      Company 4    Jobs       22
```

I tried
`dcast(myDF, Date ~ Company + value)`
and got this:

```
Date          Company 1   Company 2 Company 3 Company 4
1/1/2012         NA          NA       NA        NA
1/2/2012                
1/3/2012                     <NAs here> 
1/4/2012
```

Can someone please help me out and tell me why such a nefarious thing is occurring?

Comment: Has each company at a certain date at maximum one entry? I am assuming not, because otherwise you wouldn't get the `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` warning.

Comment: I'm confused about that warning...I double checked and I indeed have at most one value per company for date.  It's true that some values are missing, but I don't think that is the major issue.

Comment: I think that should be `dcast(myDF, Date ~ Company + variable)`

Comment: Maybe `dcast(unique(myDF), Date ~ Company, value.var = "value")`? A reproducible example would be helpful. It doesn't have to be your real data. Just a small dataset that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, this gives me a dataframe with the correct dimensions but every entry is 0!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original data frame inside function `dcast()` because your data already are in long format. Function will use column `Jobs` as values.

```
dcast(df,Date~Company)
      Date Company_1 Company_2 Company_3 Company_4
1 1/1/2012        12        84       239        22
```

You can also write exactly that you want to use column `Jobs` as values.

```
dcast(df,Date~Company,value.var="Jobs")
```

Comment: thanks for you help.  I tried both versions and got the same thing as my final attempt I wrote above, the only difference is that the NAs were replaced with 0 and 1s.  Hummm....

Comment: Then please add to your question result of dput() of your original data frame because data you supplied works as expected.

Comment: I don't mean to sound paranoid, but the real data is from a work project, and I don't want to put the information out in public.  I will have to rework it.
In the meantime, I am wondering if the warning I'm getting is giving me any useful information,   
"Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: It sounds that you have more than one observation per Date per company, so you have to decide what to do with repeated observations (mean, maximal).

Comment: Well, after examining the original dataset, I found that is not the case...however I did notice someone has the same problem here:  http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/1287e9kena/r-reshape2s-dcast-adds-nas-to-data-frame

Comment: Even if you cannot post the data here, some additional information would be helpful, as for example `lapply( myDF, class )` or `any( duplicated( myDF[ , c("Company", "Date") ] ))`.